# Why do the Android Keyboard pops up when adding a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-softkeyboard

I'm facing a weird problem when adding a `ListView` to my layout.

My layout contains 2 `EditText` and when I start the activity, the keyboard doesn't pop automatically. But when I add a `ListView` anywhere in the layout, the keyboard pop up when the activity starts.

I know there are many ways to hide the keyboard like this one: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)` and you may have seen other solutions to the problems like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668210/automatic-popping-up-keyboard-on-start-activity) but my question is not how to prevent this but ***why*** is this happening ?

I have created a simple example to demonstrate this behavior

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="chadi.projects.code.TestKeyboardActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If this `ListView` doesn't exist, the keyboard don't show up. If I replace the `ListView` by other views, it still doesn't show up. Only when I add a simple `ListView` (even wihtout populating it with anything), is the keboard showing up.

***Why*** is this happening?

Comment: Maybe the `EditText` has the focus when you start your new activity

Comment: I have tried it with `<requestFocus />` on one and/or both `EditText`. The keyboard only pops up when a `ListView` is added anywhere in the layout regarding on where i added the `<requestFocus />`

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Comment: You're right, it works! It's the same if we write it in Java like I stated above, but my question focus on ***why*** do we need to explicitly write this when specifically adding a `ListView` to our layout?

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to add request focus to your edit text
like this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
<requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: No ! Your solution doesn't work. I don't want to let the keyboard pops up when starting the activity. In addition, even when I add the `requestFocus` , only when I add the `ListView` is the keyboard poping up.